# How to check if its a digit and repeat when its not

Tags: c

The code below just loops infinitely even with the `break;`. I'm trying to make it so if the user types something other than a number it asks again.

```
int x,y;
while(1)
{
    printf("x: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("y: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    if(isdigit(x)&&isdigit(y))
    {
        break;
    }
}
printf("X: %d Y: %d",x,y);
```

Comment: Integers are values (like two or three). Digits are parts of representations, like the '2' character in the string "523". In this code, `x` and `y` are `int` variables that hold integer values. What do you think it means to check if an integer is a digit? It's not clear from your question what you wanted to do, but if you wanted to read in a line of string input and see if it consists entirely of digits, your code doesn't reflect that wish at all.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm sorry if the question wasnt clear. English isnt my native language and I also have limited programming knowledge since I've just started learning. This piece of code is something that is going to be part of an assignment for class, which is kind of a battleship game with a few changes. What I'm trying to do is to make the program ask the user for the x and y coordenates, and if the user types anything other than numbers, it asks again.

Comment: @Carlos So then you do want to read in a line of input and see if it contains anything other than digits. Your code does not reflect that. Your code reads an integer, not a line. And then it checks if it *is* a digit, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks for the correction.  As I said, I'm still starting. Can you give me some tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

x and y will never be digits, because digits range from 0x30 to 0x39 (in the case of ascii encoding). You are reading them with the %d modifier, use the %c modifier instead.

Comment: DIgits can have any range of adjascent values. There is no guarantee for ASCII encoding.